# unpacking elements in list for writing csv in python 3.7

Tags: python, csv

I have a list like this:

```
L1 = [['myname'], [12.33333333333334]]
```

I want to write these items in a csv file, I can do this, but the problem is that the output is like this:

```
['myname'],[12.33333333333334]
```

I want my output gone be like this:

```
myname , 12.33333333333334
```

Comment: When you are writing a field to csv get the zeroth element before writing. Eg . `field_to_write[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution.

```
import csv
L1 = [['myname'], [12.33333333333334]]
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    mywriter.writerow(L1[0] + L1[1])
```

Comment: wow, it was near my nose, i had wrote same you but with a little difference.        this---->  mywriter.writerow(L1[0],L1[1])

Comment: tnx a lot  Vishvajit

Comment: You're welcome. Upvote the answer please :P

Comment: definitely :)---